# Splitting two columns for which combine due to large values

Tags: python, awk

I have a data file containing two columns with 60,000 lines. Until line number about 24,9900 there is a empty space between the two columns. Beyond that, (since the values are big) there is no empty space between the two columns. Looks like single column only. With this data, I can not plot graph using xmgrace.

```
249985.0013132.505
```

For plotting graph in xmgrace the data should be separated (must have space in between like:

```
249985.00   13132.505
```

So I used awk to separate them.

```
awk '{print $1, $2}' out_average_diffusion-maltoLyo12perX.dat
```

But it fail to separate into two column.

What should be done for separating those columns?

Appreciate if this can be done in python too.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know when column 1 ends? Does it have a fixed width? How do you know the fields are "249985.00" and "13132.505" instead of "249985.001" and "3132.505"?

Comment: The first column has its fixed width and also the second column. Both have 9 spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sed command may work for you:

```
sed 's/\(.\{9\}\)/\1 /' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk '{ if (NR > 24990) print substr($1, 0, 10) " " substr($1, 10); else print }' out_average_diffusion-maltoLyo12perX.dat
```